# Laravel Blade echo and variables

Tags: laravel, echo, laravel-blade

I'm trying to understand Laravel, but i'm stuck

When I try this code:

```
@foreach($nerds as $key =>$value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->nerd_level }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

it displays litterally "{{ $value->id }}" etc in a list on the site.

Anyone?

Comment: Does your view filename end in `.blade.php`? Views with only the `.php` extension will not be interpreted and compiled by Blade.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you change the syntax from `{{ $value->id }}` to `{!! $value->id !!}`?

Comment: @TimLewis Escaping (or not) the variable value shouldn't make any difference in this case, because the response is printing the actual view file contents without parsing it at all.

Comment: @Bogdan That's true. I couldn't remember the exact functionality of `{!! !!}`,and your comment is probably the right solution, but you never know.

Comment: No, I use laravel 4. So it has to be {{ }}. Also the function @foreach is litterally printed.

Comment: I don't want to make too many assumptions about where your code is located within the file structure.  You could check to see if PHP is being interpreted.  Something like `<?php echo 'blah'; ?>` should work if php is being interpreted.